# Syntax error at buffered='yes' in an open statement

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am writing a Fortran program in which one line is written like this

```
open(unit=un1,file=filenm,form='unformatted',buffered='yes',status='replace',buffercount=127)
```

I have defined

```
character*256 filenm.
un1=11
```

but still I am getting error

```
"Syntax error at or near =" in that line..
```

Comment: Just as a note, `character*256` is outdated. You should use `character(len=256) :: filename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the `buffered='yes'`, which is not standard Fortran, but some vendor extension and your compiler does not recognize it. I would just delete it and also delete the `buffercount=127` (mentioned in the comment).

Modern compilers and operating systems allow control of these things (external I/O buffering) by other means. For example, using environment variables in gfortran https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Runtime.html#Runtime

Comment: thanks..   i deleted buffered='yes' as well as buffercount=127 also,so that error is gone but new error "Derived type has not been declared - t_openfilename"  has come in line                                                                             type(T_OPENFILENAME) ofn

Comment: Re your error message about the derived type t_openfilename not declared.   With just the source code line that causes the error we can only guess.  You need to declare that type before it is used.  Why is it missing?  Are you missing a file that defines it?

Comment: thanks for reply.......actually i am from electrical background..i am trying to learn fortran for my project....please tell me any good reference from which i will get the knowledge of "type command"

Comment: @user991852 : important, very important: learn Fortran 95, and the distinction between old F77 constructs and new ones. Don't use old constructs. Learn to read them (if you have old code to understand) but don't use them. In particular, never use commons, namelists, or code outside modules. Always use implicit none, and specification of intent in the routine arguments.

Comment: References: I recommend the book "Fortran 95/2003 Explained" by Metcalf, Reid and Cohen.   For an overview, but probably too brief to learn from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features